# theme contact form block

Tags: theming

I am using contact_form_blocks-7.x-1.x-dev module. Using this module I have embedd contact us form in my website. For themeing I have created file named **block--contact.tpl.php**. Cleared cache, but it doesnt result anything.
How should I theme this contact us form?

Comment: How did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

For themeing contact form we can use the FORM_ID which is contact_site_form. The code snippet will be as follows

```
function myTheme_theme() {
  return array(
'contact_site_form' => array(
'render element' => 'form',
'template' => 'contact-site-form',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'myTheme').'/templates',
),
  );
}
function myTheme_preprocess_contact_site_form(&$vars) {
$vars['contact'] = drupal_render_children($vars['form']);

}
```

That should get you the ability to create a template file called contact-site-form.tpl.php.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to theme contact form then you can do it using  [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

Use `hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)` in your theme's template.php and alter the form the way you want to theme it.